# JSON unset element at specific index in php

Tags: php, json, rest, unset

I have two REST urls that I'm using. The first one has event profiles and in my code I'm looping through the and searching each of those in the second rest url.

Comment: Things get so much easier if you use `foreach` instead of `for` to loop over array elements.

Comment: `unset($eventRuleID);` doesn't unset anything in the array. What's the point of it?

Comment: `unset($policyPayloadCopy["EventProfile"][$counter]["EventRuleIDList"]["EventRuleID"][$index]);` is how you unset an array element.

Comment: A better way to do this is with `array_filter()`, to keep the array elements whose severity are in `$checkedArr`.

Comment: If you do `$a = 1; $b = $a; unset($b);` it only unsets `$b`, not `$a`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_filter()` to keep the elements that match the filtering criteria, rather than unsetting elements during a loop.

```
foreach ($policyPayloadCopy["EventProfile"] as &$profile) {
    if (count($profile["EventRuleIDList"]["EventRuleID"]) > 1) {
        $profile["EventRuleIDList"]["EventRuleID"] = array_filter($profile["EventRuleIDList"]["EventRuleID"], function($rule) use ($checkedArr) {
            return in_array($rule["Severity"], $checkedArr);
        });
    }
}
```

The reference variable `&$profile` means that the assignment to `$profile["EventRuleIDList"]["EventRuleID"]` affects the original `$policyPayloadCopy` array rather than a copy.